# Building an string from properties values of objects in a list using linq

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I have a list of employees and I want to build an string with a comma separated  with all LastNames from all on them.

Sample data:

```
Emp1.LastName = "A"
Emp2.LastName = "B"
Emp3.LastName = "C"

Dim listing As List(Of Employee)
dim flatted as string
```

At the end I want to get

```
 flatted = "A,B,C"
```

The point is that I want to do it using **linq** (vb or c#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it would be done in C#.  I am using a slightly different class (Person, rather than Employee), but the code will end up being the same.

```
// Make some experimental data...  
List<Person> peeps = new List<Person>()
{
    new Person() { FirstName = "Frank", LastName = "Jax" },
    new Person() { FirstName = "Anne", LastName = "Wax" },
};

// This will select all of the last names from the list of people, and join them with commas.
string lastNames = string.Join(",", (from x in peeps select x.LastName));
```

And the class listing, for the curious.

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should work:

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
        people.Add(new Person() { LastName = "A" });
        people.Add(new Person() { LastName = "B" });
        people.Add(new Person() { LastName = "C" });

        var lastNames = (from person in people
                         select person.LastName);

        var result = string.Join(",", lastNames);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```